# object has two materials at once? Why?

Tags: materials

This isn't my mesh, but, I downloaded it off the internet to animate and screw with the materials. Either I'm a complete noob, the mesh wasn't formatted correctly, or both, but, after changing the material of a few of the gun barrels, strange things happen when I try to render an animation.

Here are a few sample frames and a link to the file. What is going on and how the hell do I fix it?
(pay close attention to the minigun cylinders on the left
[image]
[image]
[image]
LINK TO BLENDER FILE
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxf7lERLL3TlRjV3YkJCSHRKN1U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is cloned.
You have a complete mesh (MECH_MESH) and the same but in 195 separate objects (MECH_MESH.001,MECH_MESH.002, ..., MECH_MESH.195). This could be for easy damage or something like that (?) but destroys the surface whan rendering (faces overlapping).

Anyway, just select MECH_MESH (right click until you select the good one or use outliner) and move it to another layer (with <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> or number of your layer) to get a good render. Setting the objects on different layers will allow easy selection (and then deletion, hidding, toggle renderablity,...).

Comment: Ah thank you,  I did not see that mesh and I also had not realized that the animation mesh if moved to a different layer would still effect the old one. Much thanks!